# Calling the Facebook API from CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, rest, facebook-graph-api, phantomjs

I'm trying to call the facebook API using casperJS, using a url like so:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<APP_ID>/accounts/test-users?installed=false&name=Joe&locale=en_US&method=post&access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

It works fine when I put it in a browser (I get a perfectly fine JSON result), but I get an about:blank page when I try to access it in a casperJS script. I've tried various methods:

```
casper.open(url);
casper.open(url, { method: 'post' });
casper.open(url, { method: 'get' }); // even though it should be a post...
casper.open(url, { method: 'put' }); // still trying stuff
casper.open(baseUrl, { method: 'post', data: { ... } });
```

When I get the current url, it is about:blank, and when I get the content, it's just an empty page:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [getPageContent() docs](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getpagecontent):

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var url = '<your url here>';

casper.start().then(function() {
    this.open(url, {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    });
});

casper.run(function() {
    require('utils').dump(JSON.parse(this.getPageContent()));
    this.exit();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. The sample works fine (twitter.com call). However, in my Facebook Graph Api request, it returns a json object. However, Casper reads it as an HTML document formatted with a pre tag that contains the json. Any ideas on how to tell Casper not to do this?

Comment: Hey, I figured it out. Even though it returns HTML, I was able to parse it using `this.getHTML('pre')`.

Comment: @NiKo in my script the i keep on getting the JSON object again and again, any ideas on how i can stop the execution of the script.this is the link to the problem :

Comment: @NiKo in my script the i keep on getting the JSON object again and again, any ideas on how i can stop the execution of the script.this is the link to the problem : –[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392373/casperjs-script-never-exits)

Comment: This is partially usefull. How to you get the status code if request fails?