# Batch script exits and closes console after casperjs call but not for phantomjs/node/js/python etc

Tags: batch-file, cmd, casperjs

This casperjs sample code runs fine and it doesn't terminate the console after finishing when I load it directly in cmd. But when I execute it in a batch file, all of the code after the casperjs call doesn't seem to be executed and cmd closes immediately.  I'm certain this isn't a problem with the batch file syntax because I've used this same code template for many files and languages.  Why might this happen?

casperjs sample code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://casperjs.org/', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.thenOpen('http://phantomjs.org', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.run();
```

batch script:

```
@echo off
ECHO inside sample
set args=""
ECHO.
:RELOAD_SCRIPT
casperjs C:\Users\Murphy\Documents\MEGA\repos\Javascript\CasperJs\sample.js %args%
ECHO.
ECHO.
:PROMPT
set /p UserInput= Press "Enter" to reload. ("n" to exit)
IF "%UserInput%"=="n" (
    GOTO :EXIT
) Else (
    set args=%UserInput%
    GOTO :RELOAD_SCRIPT
)
:EXIT
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CasperJS script never exits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392373/casperjs-script-never-exits)

Comment: Yes I think this has something to do with it.  I'm trying to test sending an enter key after casper finishes to see if that works.

Comment: Yes, it might not be a perfect duplicate and I don't know the intrinsics of batch scripts, but the solution is to use CasperJS from git which has an exe and shouldn't lead to this problem like I said in the linked post.

Comment: I changed casperjs in the batch script to the casper.exe path and that fixed it.  Thanks!