# Caspjer output in the Console on WIndows

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am running a casperjs script on Windows Server 2012 R2. The script executes well but when I run the script in the console, instead of waiting until the script is executed what happens is that I get another input to write another command and suddenly the logs appears there.

I recorded a video of what happens in this environment here:

http://recordit.co/GPVQPMiqDp

and what I expect is this:

http://recordit.co/Np8O1Atq7b

THe second video is with the same version of casperjs and phantomjs but in a WIndows 7 environment.

ANy help will be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CasperJS script never exits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392373/casperjs-script-never-exits)